# Method 'QueryBuilder' not found in class ObjectRepository

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, phpstorm, query-builder

New to Symfony & Doctrine

I trying to fetch a selection of objects from a MySQL database via Doctrine in a Symfony project. I am doing this with **createQueryBuilder**;

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('mcsyncBundle:DB');
$query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('p')
    ->select('p')
    ->where('(p.created=:)' . $till)
    ->setParameter('created', $till)
    ->orderBy('p.created', 'ASC')
    ->getQuery();
$PackDB = $query->getResult();
```

But I keep getting the error:

```
*Method 'QueryBuilder' not found in class \Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectRepository*.
```

Anyone that can explain (fix) this problem?

EDIT: This error is coming from inside PHPStorm by the way and NOT from Symfony itself

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suppose you wrote that code in a *Controler* file. QueryBuilders are meant to be in **Repository** files. For `/Entity/Plop.php`, you should have `/Entity/PlopRepository.php` as well.

**PlopRepository.php**

```
namespace Foo\BarBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class PlopRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function getCreatedP()
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
                  ->select('p')
                  ->where('p.created = :created')
                  ->setParameter('created', $till)
                  ->orderBy('p.created', 'ASC');

        return $qb->getQuery()
                  ->getResults();
     }
     // ...
}
```

**EDIT 1** : and there was a mistake in your `->where('...')` statement I fixed ;)

**EDIT 2** : to be complete, controller part :

**TotoController.php**

```
public function getPlopAction() 
{
     $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
     $plopRepository = $entityManager->getRepository('FooBarBundle:Plop');  
     $plops = $plopRepository->getCreatedP();
     // ...
}
```

Comment: And the TS said; "Let there be light!" *(Thanks for explanation and the statement fix!)*

Comment: Great ! Be careful, there was an extra `getQuery()` call in my answer. I edited my post ;)

Comment: I added controller part. Can't help myself improving my answers :)